# How to prevent auto-generated 'T' letter when parsing String to LocalDateTime using DateTimeFormatterBuilder

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

I have this fragment of code to bidirectional parsing String to LocalDateTime:

```
public class ConvertLocalDateToString {

private static final DateTimeFormatter CUSTOM_LOCAL_DATE;
static {
    CUSTOM_LOCAL_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .toFormatter();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "2020-02-18 15:04:30";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, CUSTOM_LOCAL_DATE); //2020-02-18T15:04:30

    LocalDateTime addedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime.plusHours(10).format(CUSTOM_LOCAL_DATE.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
    System.out.println(addedDateTime);
    System.out.println(dateTime); //2020-02-18T15:04:30

}
```

My assumption is 'T' letter is auto-generated by ISO-8601 format. This caused:

> DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-02-18 15:04:30' could not be parsed at index 10

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: The T is not there in the LocalDateTime.  It's only an artefact of how System.out.println works.  If you want a different format, then use one to format your LocalDateTime before you print it.

Comment: It’s a little hard to see at a glance, but your second call to `LocalDateTime.parse` is not actually passing CUSTOM_LOCAL_DATE as a second parameter.  The [one-argument LocalDate.parse method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) expects an ISO 8601 format, including the `T`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(dateTime)` is the same as `System.out.println(String.valueOf(dateTime))`.

`String.valueOf(dateTime)` is the same as `dateTime.toString()`, except it can handle `null` value.

Calling `toString()` on a `LocalDateTime` is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--) to do this:

> Outputs this date-time as a String, such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30`.
>
> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
> - uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

If you want different format, call [`format(DateTimeFormatter formatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-).

---

So, to answer your questions:

> *My assumption is 'T' letter is auto-generated by ISO-8601 format.*

The `T` is no more auto-generated than the `-` and `:` characters.

> *How do I get rid of it?*

Call `format(...)` and specify the format you want, e.g.

```
System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
```